# get maximum valued dictionary from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this list.

```
dict_list = [{"rp":1,"vi":100},{"rp":2,"vi":70},{"rp":1,"vi":200},{"rp":1,"vi":150},{"rp":2,"vi":300},{"rp":3, "vi":120 }]
```

I want output as:

```
[ {"rp":1,"vi":200},{"rp":2,"vi":300},{"rp":3,"vi":120}]
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: What did you try so far and why did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a temporary dictionary using the 'rp' values as keys and feeding the data in order of 'vi' value to retain the highest 'vi' value for each unique 'rp' key.  Then convert the values of that temporary dictionary into a list of dictionaries:

```
R = [*{d["rp"]:d for d in sorted(dict_list,key=lambda d:d["vi"])}.values()]

print(R)

[{'rp': 2, 'vi': 300}, {'rp': 1, 'vi': 200}, {'rp': 3, 'vi': 120}]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create a dictionary with key as the `rp` value and value as the maximum `vi` value.

Use the created dictionary to create the required list

```
dict_list = [{"rp":1,"vi":100},{"rp":2,"vi":70},{"rp":1,"vi":200},{"rp":1,"vi":150},{"rp":2,"vi":300},{"rp":3, "vi":120 }]
res = dict()
for elt in dict_list:
    res[elt["rp"]] = max(res.get(elt["rp"], 0), elt["vi"]) # overwrite with max for matching keys

dict_list = [{"rp": key, "vi": value}  for key, value in res.items()]
print(dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant way to do it but I hope it helps.

you can try to use pandas for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_list = [{"rp":1,"vi":100},{"rp":2,"vi":70},{"rp":1,"vi":200}, 
{"rp":1,"vi":150},{"rp":2,"vi":300},{"rp":3, "vi":120 }]
full = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)

rp_list = pd.Series(full['rp']).unique()
new= []

for rp in rp_list:
    values = full.loc[full['rp'] == rp]
    max_value = values["vi"].max()
    new.append({'rp':rp,'vi':max_value})
print (new)
```